# Abstração de dados entre duas tabelas usando o datalayer

Tags: php

Estou usando o https://github.com/robsonvleite/datalayer

Preciso fazer a abstração de dados da tabela **projetos**. Como a tabela projetos tem relação com outras, junto preciso abstrair dados das tabelas **Cadastro** e **Paises**.

**Em Models tenho:**

Cadastro.php

```
<?php
namespace Source\Models;
use CoffeeCode\DataLayer\DataLayer;

class Cadastro extends DataLayer
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct("cadastro", []);
    }
}
```

Paises.php

```
<?php
namespace Source\Models;
use CoffeeCode\DataLayer\DataLayer;

class Pais extends DataLayer
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct("paises", []);
    }
}
```

Projetos.php

```
<?php
namespace Source\Models;
use CoffeeCode\DataLayer\DataLayer;

class Projeto extends DataLayer
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct("projetos", []);
    }
}
```

Na tela de onde exibo os projetos:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

$model = new \Source\Models\Projeto();
$projetos = $model->find("url = :url", "url=".$_GET['url']."")->fetch();

foreach ($projetos as $projeto){ 
   echo $projeto->titulo
}
?>
```

Como fazer, para que na mesma abstração `$projeto->` eu consiga trazer dados das outras tabelas?

Comment: Pergunta básica: esse Datalayer possui suporte a relacionamento de tabelas?

Comment: @Woss Sim, esse video explica, mas falando de outra tabela, não conseguir compreender. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eD067TOeE-k